# Having issues with PowerShell syntax

Tags: powershell

Example:

HDD Capacity: " + "{0:N2}" -f

What does **" + "**  do and what does it mean?

Learning powershell.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an incomplete statement there. You're missing a leading quote and the actual data to the right of the [`-f (Format operator`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f). When used with strings, `+` concatenates the strings:

```
PS > "HDD Capacity: " + "{0:N2}"
HDD Capacity: {0:N2}
PS >
```

The format operator will take that string (wnich can be coded as a single string) and fomrat the numerical value to the right to two decimal places:

```
PS > "HDD Capacity: {0:N2}" -f 365.987
HDD Capacity: 365.99
PS >
```

I used a hard-coded value here to focus on the action of the `-f` operator, but in practice, you would use a variable or expression that retrieves the hard drive capacity.